# How can I measure speedups on my application when performance varies on my machine?

Tags: performance, c++

I work on a monolithic program running on Linux that's very memory intensive. We're having trouble tweaking the speed of this program on most of our large memory machines because the performance is inconsistent, varying up to 15% from one run to the next. One machine, for example, has 2TB of memory and 80 Xeon E7-4870 (2.4Ghz) processors on it. How can we determine the source of this variability and/or improve the accuracy of our measurements so that we can determine which speedups work and by how much? It's running SUSE11.

Here's what we've tried so far:
1) Disabled TurboBoost in the BIOS.
2) Running the program lots of times and averaging the results. This works, but it'll take weeks to eliminate the noise.

Comment: What are your bottlenecks? Do you write anything to a disk?

Comment: Also, are any other processes running on the same machine?

Comment: Very little disk or swapping - it's a CPU bound application. No other processes running of significance. It occurs cache could be responsible but seems like a lot of variation for cache.

Comment: If it's CPU-bound the best bet you can do is to profile your code, using tools such as the ones pointed by fede.evol and determine where you are spending most of your processing time. If it is also multi-threaded, then it's possible some threads aren't being executed properly or are hanging the other threads.

Comment: I don't think you understand the nature of the question. You use a profiler to identify a hot spot and come up a tweak to speed things up. A good software engineer will verify that the tweak does indeed speed things up and that's where I'm running into trouble. Running the same program multiple times can result in wide variations in performance, showing small slowdowns in some cases and big speedups in other cases so I can't test whether my tweaks are actually working! It's a problem I've noticed on our newer machines. Unfortunately, for some tweaks only the newer machines have enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to answer without more specific details: type of application (I/O vs calculation intensive vs networked app), additional processes running and so on.

But I'd throw in some generic suggestions:

-) Use [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/examples/) to try to understand where the system (and the specific application) is most of the time. This tool is very very powerfull even if it takes a bit to extrapolate it's output for complicate applications.

-) Use tools such as iostat, iotop, pidstat, vmstat to try to analyze if there are bottlenecks in the I/O section or memory consumption/paging and so on.